# RTK stream without base station in DJI Mavic 2 Enterprise Advanced

Tags: gps, rtkgps+, dji

New drone operator here. We recently acquired a DJI Mavic 2 Enterprise Advanced. It comes with an RTK Module. We are based in Iowa, USA and the state has a free Real-Time Network Service (NTRIP) available for all. On the DJI Pilot apps, the RTK menu, I am providing the following settings as shown in the image below. It connects to the service every 5/10 seconds and stays connected for 2-3 seconds then disconnected for another few seconds. DJI Pilot also notifies that the RTK connection is weak and the aircraft is unable to take off. Once I disable the RTK module, the GPS works fine and the flight works as expected. Is there any way of connecting the RTK module without using an expensive base station (Trimble or Leica)?

[image]